# C# API Controller Custom Filter with HttpActionContext Redirect to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

Is there a way to create a custom filter with an API controller to redirect to a MVC controller?

After looking around a bit his is what i have.

```
public class APIHasOneOfThesePermissions : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }
    private SAMPortal.DAL.SAMPortalContext db = new DAL.SAMPortalContext();
    public string[] Permissions { get; set; }

    public APIHasOneOfThesePermissions(string[] Permissions)
    {
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.db));
        this.Permissions = Permissions;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        string userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var CurrUser = db.Users.Include(u => u.Role.Permissions).Where(user => user.Id.Equals(userID)).FirstOrDefault();

        bool hasPermission = false;

        foreach (string x in Permissions)
        {
            if (hasPermission == false)
            {
                hasPermission = CurrUser.HasPermission(x);
            }
        }

        if (hasPermission == false)
        {
            filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

However when i execute the code it doesn't redirect them to the error page. Ideally i would like to redirect to a specify non-API controller is that possible?

Comment: Sean - did you ever find an answer to this?  I am running into a similar issue. - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've created AuthorizeRedirectAttribute in one of my projects like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyNamespace.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class AuthorizeRedirectAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string RedirectUrl = "~/Error/Forbidden403";

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

            var httpContext = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            var response = httpContext.Response;

            // If AJAX request, just return appropriate code
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                else
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
                response.End();
            }

            // Otherwise check if authenticated, and if not redirect to specified url
            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect(RedirectUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've used it like this

```
[AuthorizeRedirect(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
}
```

In this case I've decorated whole controller with this attribute. It can also be applied to single controller function, if necessary. Basically what it does is, it checks whether logged on user is in role Administrator. If it is not, user is redirected to "~/Error/Forbidden403" action (returning simple view displaying user has not enough permissions). Hope it helps.

You could also implement checking your own permissions, as you did in your code.

Comment: So what you have done will work with an non-api controller but in this case i need this to work with an API controller, that is why i was using the HttpActionContext instead of the AuthorizationContext which won't work with api controllers

Comment: Sorry, redirection was somewhat misguided ;) I think it is not advisable to redirect from API controller. Throw an error instead and let client decide what to do when certain error occurs. If user is not logged in, for example, return 401 HTTP code. If user has no permissions, return 403 HTTP code, etc. Also in your code there is no redirection mechanism involved. You're simply returning NotAuthorized (401), which IMO should be Forbidden (403).