# Login Dialog Appears When User is Not Authorized

Tags: c#, angularjs, web, asp.net-web-api

In an attempt to implement security in my web app, I created an attribute that derives from `AuthorizeAttribute`.

```
public class FunctionalityAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string FunctionalityName { get; set; }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string adGroup = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[FunctionalityName];

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(adGroup)) { return true; }

        return false; // This causes a login dialog to appear. I don't want that.
    }
}
```

And here is how it's used in my Web API method:

```
[Functionality(FunctionalityName = "GetApps")]
public IEnumerable<ApplicationDtoSlim> Get()
{
    using (var prestoWcf = new PrestoWcf<IApplicationService>())
    {
        return prestoWcf.Service.GetAllApplicationsSlim().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

It actually works. But the issue is what happens when I'm not authorized:

[image]

I don't want that dialog to come up. I'm already signed in. I want to let the user know that they're not authorized. How do I make it so that login dialog doesn't come up?

Comment: Simply throw Exception - `throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);`

Comment: That didn't work. I still get the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`, use `HttpStatusCode` `Forbidden` because `Unauthorized` causes a login prompt to display. Here is the entire attribute class.

```
public class FunctionalityAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string FunctionalityName { get; set; }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string adGroup = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[FunctionalityName];

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(adGroup)) { return true; }

        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Authenticated, but not authorized.
        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Use Forbidden because Unauthorized causes a login prompt to display.
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm handling it in my angular repository:

```
    $http.get('/PrestoWeb/api/apps/')
        .then(function (result) {
            // do success stuff
        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status == 403) {
                $rootScope.setUserMessage("Unauthorized");
                callbackFunction(null);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also override HandleUnauthorizedRequest

```
  protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary rd = null;
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Redirect to Not Authorized
        rd = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "NotAuthorized", controller = "Error", area = "" });
    }
    else
    {
        //Redirect to Login
        rd = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Account", area = "" });
        //See if we need to include a ReturnUrl
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl) && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl != "/")
            rd.Add("ReturnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl);
    }
    //Set context result
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(rd);
  }
```

Comment: I shouldn't need the `else` part of that because that's what would happen anyway. I tried the first part and my page loaded instead of going to an error page. But that could be because of my routing with AngularJS interfering. Or I need to actually create the error page. Working on it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In our projects we keep both, because this override is invoked in both cases: [1] User isn't logged in, [2] User is logged in but doesn't have appropriate access.  Additionally we also have a slightly different exe path if filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()

Comment: In the first part of the `if`, you're creating a new `RouteValueDictionary`, but I don't see where you actually do anything with it (like return it, or invoke it somehow). Does just creating it cause the redirect to happen? For example, you assign it to the `rd` variable, but then don't do anything with that variable.

Comment: Edited to show usage.  It got sanitized when removing irrelevant code by accident

Comment: My `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` takes an `HttpActionContext` instead of an `AuthorizationContext`. Need to figure out how to put the redirect in there. I found a link where someone said this: "I think it is not advisable to redirect from API controller. Throw an error instead and let client decide what to do when certain error occurs." Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31256862/279516